# Create loop and add new Rows for csv in iMacros

Tags: loops, automation, imacros

I have a website from where I want to extract data : `http://220.225.242.179/locm.asp`

I want to loop say 15 times to get data for Number form say 164497 to 164512. See line number 4 below in code, where `Content` is specified. How do I Achieve this? I am looking for a `loop` adding so that I specify starting number and ending number and all data which is extracted gets stored in the `CSV` File.

Thanks in advance.

```
VERSION BUILD=8920312 RECORDER=FX
TAB T=1
URL GOTO=http://220.225.242.179/locm.asp
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=NAME:FrontPage_Form1 ATTR=NAME:mrn CONTENT=164497
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT FORM=NAME:FrontPage_Form1 ATTR=NAME:B1
SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO
TAG POS=3 TYPE=TABLE ATTR=TXT:* EXTRACT=TXT
'Membership no
TAG POS=4 TYPE=FONT ATTR=TXT:* EXTRACT=TXT
'Member Name
TAG POS=6 TYPE=FONT ATTR=TXT:* EXTRACT=TXT
'Gender
TAG POS=8 TYPE=FONT ATTR=TXT:* EXTRACT=TXT
'Pin Code
TAG POS=24 TYPE=FONT ATTR=TXT:* EXTRACT=TXT
'Mem Type
TAG POS=29 TYPE=FONT ATTR=TXT:* EXTRACT=TXT
SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=c:\PortableApps FILE=mytable_{{!NOW:yymmdd_hhnnss}}.csv
```

I have tried

```
Set !LOOP 90
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=NAME:FrontPage_Form1 ATTR=NAME:mrn CONTENT=1644{{!LOOP}}
```

But this create multiple CSV Files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
VERSION BUILD=8920312 RECORDER=FX
TAB T=1
URL GOTO=http://220.225.242.179/locm.asp
SET startLoop 164497
SET !LOOP {{startLoop}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=NAME:FrontPage_Form1 ATTR=NAME:mrn CONTENT={{!LOOP}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT FORM=NAME:FrontPage_Form1 ATTR=NAME:B1
SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO
TAG POS=3 TYPE=TABLE ATTR=TXT:* EXTRACT=TXT
'Membership no
TAG POS=4 TYPE=FONT ATTR=TXT:* EXTRACT=TXT
'Member Name
TAG POS=6 TYPE=FONT ATTR=TXT:* EXTRACT=TXT
'Gender
TAG POS=8 TYPE=FONT ATTR=TXT:* EXTRACT=TXT
'Pin Code
TAG POS=24 TYPE=FONT ATTR=TXT:* EXTRACT=TXT
'Mem Type
TAG POS=29 TYPE=FONT ATTR=TXT:* EXTRACT=TXT
SET nowVar EVAL("('{{!LOOP}}' == '{{startLoop}}') ? '{{!NOW:yymmdd_hhnnss}}' : '{{nowVar}}';")    
SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=c:\PortableApps FILE=mytable_{{nowVar}}.csv
```

It doesn't create multiple CSV files, because the file name stays the same.